# catching form data in django views

Tags: python, django, post

I have a form which submits some data using POST, here is what I receive when I see the local variables :

```
data    
<QueryDict: {u'movieYearTxt': [u'1234'], u'hiddenmovieId': [u''], u'movieNameTxt': [u'asd'], u'movieInfoAdd': [u'Submit'], u'genreSelect': [u'Crime', u'Historical']}>
```

where data = request.POST
But when I try to catch genreSelected I only get "Historical",

While in the Request information I see:

```
POST
Variable        Value
movieYearTxt    u'1234'
hiddenmovieId   u''
movieNameTxt    u'asd'
movieInfoAdd    u'Submit'
genreSelect     u'Historical'
```

How do I catch all the values of genreSelect
Django version = 1.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 request.POST.getlist('genreSelected')
```

Or you may want to use form to parse and validate POST values.